# Can not run OSGI bundle

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am trying to collect bundle, but get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: *** Package 'sun.misc' is not imported by bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core [12], nor is there any bundle that exports package 'sun.misc'. However, the class 'sun.misc.Unsafe' is available from the system class loader. There are two fixes: 1) Add package 'sun.misc' to the 'org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra' property and modify bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core [12] to import this package; this causes the system bundle to export class path packages. 2) Add package 'sun.misc' to the 'org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation' property; a library or VM bug can cause classes to be loaded by the wrong class loader. The first approach is preferable for preserving modularity. ***
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2031)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Unsafe not found by org.apache.camel.camel-core [12]
```

I'm using `apache camel`, `camel-mail` and `apache felix plugin`

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0              
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.camel.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>com.camel.mail</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>osgi-bundle</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <instructions>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            <Bundle-Version>1.0</Bundle-Version>
                            <Bundle-Activator>com.camel.mail.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                            <Import-Package>
                                *;resolution:=optional
                            </Import-Package>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As I understand it, I need to add package `'sun.misc'` to the `'org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra'`, but I do not understand how to do it

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to run Camel in Karaf or?

Comment: I tried to run in Apache ServiceMix, but get an error: `ERROR: Bundle com.camel.mail [223] Error starting jardir:D:\Programs\apache-servicemix-7.0.0.M2\deploy\classes (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.camel.mail [223].)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/CamelContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) .....Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.CamelContext not found by com.camel.mail [223]`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "sun.*" to the org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation property.